# How to start PHP7.0-FPM in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, php-7, fpm

By going through all answers I could find, I don't seem to be able to launch fpm 7. If I go into the container and I manually run: `service php7.0-fpm start` everything works fine.

What I have tried I:
`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;", "php7.0-fpm"]`

What I have tried II:
`CMD ["php7.0-fpm", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

What I have tried III:
`CMD ["php-fpm7.0", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

What I have tried IV:
`RUN service php7.0-fpm start`
`CMD ["php-fpm7.0", "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

PS:
Nginx works fine.

PPS:
I would like to avoid the usage of supervisor if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was on the same issue with you and I had done dozens of combinations then I found the one that works!

Since CMD overridden each other, we have to combine the commands into the same line with &&.

Here is what I have done.

```
CMD service php7.0-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: thanks mate, that's it. Damn sometimes it can be so simple. haha. Fantastic

Comment: Thank you very much! I also went through all the possible commands and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: FYI: Here's a solution to using exec form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46803057/361842